# Update to last version after already installed old

Tags: version, php

I'm using fastcgi and my PHP version is 5.3.3 instead of 5.5 so my question is how can I update to latest PHP version? I'm using CentOS, I tried yum update, but no update appeared for this.

Answer (score 0):

Normally you need to uninstall the 5.3 branch and install 5.5 from scratch because it is not an update but a new version. 
Beware that in 5.5 quite some functions are deprecated that were still available in 5.3!

Comment: ye that's not problem, but how to install it when I type yum install php-fpm lighttpd-fastcgi I will get 5.3 again, but I want 5.5 ...

Comment: Would this be helpfull? http://www.howtoforge.com/how-to-build-php-5.5-php-fpm-and-fastcgi-with-ioncube-loader-zend-opcache-and-apcu-for-ispconfig3-debian-wheezy

Answer (score 0):

http://blog.ahughes.org/?p=717

Uses the remi repository.

From the blog:

By running the following commands:

```
rpm -Uvh http://download.fedoraproject.org/pub/epel/6/i386/epel-release-6-8.noarch.rpm
rpm -Uvh http://rpms.famillecollet.com/enterprise/remi-release-6.rpm
```

you solve all dependency issues with epel and remi on CentOS 6.

Then, by running the following command, you install PHP 5.5.

```
yum --enablerepo=remi,remi-test install httpd php php-common
```

For extra goodies, you can run the following command:

```
yum --enablerepo=remi,remi-test install php-pecl-apc php-cli php-pear php-pdo php-mysqlnd php-pgsql php-pecl-mongo php-sqlite php-pecl-memcache php-pecl-memcached php-gd php-mbstring php-mcrypt php-xml
```

Now, restart your httpd service and set it to boot automatically:

```
service httpd restart
chkconfig --levels 235 httpd on
```

Now run:

```
php --version
```

to see whether the correct version of PHP was installed.